# Pug (Jade) динамическое добавление атрибута

Tags: javascript, pug, dhtml

Нужно в зависимости от переменной установить атрибут тега.

```
label(for='ff' 
  class='ff1' 
  varFlag != undefined ? eval(style= 'letter-spacing: -5px;') : eval('')
)
```

не работает. А следующий код добавляет пустой стиль, что недопустимо:

```
label(for='ff' 
  class='ff1' 
  style= varFlag != undefined ? 'letter-spacing: -5px;' : ''
)
```

в Pug можно как-то это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В последнем варианте вместо `''` поставьте `false`
https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#boolean-attributes

Comment: СпасиБо! идеально работает.

Answer (score 1):

```
if varFlag
   label.ff1(for='ff' style={'letter-spacing': '-5px'})
else
   label.ff1(for='ff')
```

https://pugjs.org/language/conditionals.html